# How to join each record of table 1 with few records of table 2?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables named report_instance and report_history (report_instance has many report_history). I want to join each report_instance with first 10 records of report_history.

**Example:**

```
report_instance r1 has 20 report_history
report_instance r2 has 5 report_history
```

The query should give me the result of joining r1 with first 10 records of 20 report_history and r2 with 5 report_history.

My Query:

```
select * 
from report_instances ri, report_history rh 
where ri.id in (select rhh.id 
                from report_history 
                where rhh.report_instance_id=ri.id limit 10);
```

I got the error:

> This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME
>   subquery'

Comment: Why is this question tagged with sqlserver when your error message is from MySQL?

Comment: means you want just first 10 report_history of each report_intance...is it..

Comment: If you need solution in mysql then I think @Giorgos has provided solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try get bellow query,

```
SELECT TOP 10 {column-name} FROM {Table-name};
```

Use for your example below,

```
select * 
from report_instances ri, report_history rh 
where ri.id in (select TOP 10 rh.id 
    from report_history 
    where rh.report_instance_id=ri.id);
```

Or,

```
select * 
from report_instances ri, report_history rh 
where ri.id in (select rh.id 
    from report_history 
    where rh.report_instance_id=ri.id 
    order by rh.id desc limit 0,10);
```

You have any error tell me.

Comment: I am getting ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10 rhh.id from report_history where rhh.report_instance_id=ri.id order by report' at line 1

Comment: u check in which query in there?

Comment: mysql --version -> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Comment: rhh change to rh your naming wrong. You have spelling  mistake.

Comment: I changed the spelling mistake.Its throwing error when i use TOP

Comment: can u update mysql sever. check sample join query working your system. first u test inner query. is this working find u check `select rh.id  from report_history where rh.report_instance_id=ri.id` check this working find.

Comment: `SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LIMIT 0 , 10`

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables, as follows, in order to get the latest-per-report_instance_id records:

```
select *,
       @rn := IF(@id = report_instance_id, @rn + 1,
                 IF(@id := report_instance_id, 1, 1)) AS rn
from report_history 
cross join (select @rn := 0, @id := 0) as vars
order by report_instance_id, id desc
```

You can use the above query as a derived table joined to `report_instances` table:

```
select ri.*, rhd.*
from report_instances as ri 
join (
    select *,
           @rn := IF(@id = report_instance_id, @rn + 1,
                     IF(@id := report_instance_id, 1, 1)) AS rn
    from report_history 
    cross join (select @rn := 0, @id := 0) as vars
    order by report_instance_id, id desc
) as rhd on ri.id = rhd.report_instance_id
where rhd.rn <= 10
```